# contextmenu on treeview not closing on left click

Tags: javascript, treeview, contextmenu

I am having a contextmenu on treeview which is functioning fine but it does not close on left click outside the treeview. I want the contextmenu to close if i do leftclick on the treeviw or outside the treeview

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        $(MyTreeDiv).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#custom-menu").css({ top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" }).show(100);

        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var container = $("#custom-menu");
            if (container.has(e.target).length == 0) {
                container.hide();

            }

        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }


});
```

Comment: I think you are not specifying "MyTreeDiv" is a ID or Class with '#' or            ' . 'symbol..

Comment: Thanks for your time Raj...MyTreeDiv is the ID but if a specify it as     $(#MyTreeDiv).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {........ OR     $(.MyTreeDiv).bind("contextmenu", function (e) { The code is not working

Comment: Add additional info like your HTML, CSS etc better if you use JSFiddle it will help others to find a solution for you.